# Personalizar "verbose_name" para administradores incrustados (admininline)

Tags: django, django-admin

Tengo varios modelos con llaves foránea a otros modelos, los cuáles incrusto en el administrador de dicho modelo usando obviamente `admin.StakedInline`, el problema es que un mismo modelo tiene hasta dos modelos hijos del mismo tipo, por lo cuál tengo que incrustar dos administradores del mismo modelo pero con diferente `fk_name`:
Administradores incrustados

```
class StatsEditionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StatsEdition
    verbose_name = _('Stats')


class ChampionCupInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Edition
    fk_name = 'champion'
    verbose_name = _("Cup's Champion")


class LocationCupInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Edition
    fk_name = 'location'
    verbose_name = _("Cup's location")


class MatchTeamOneInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Match
    fk_name = "team_1"
    verbose_name = _("Country's Matches as Team 1")


class MatchTeamTwoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Match
    fk_name = "team_2"
    verbose_name = _("Country's Matches as Team 2")


class MatchCupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Match
    fk_name = 'cup'
    verbose_name = _("Cup's Matches")
```

Administrador principal:

```
@admin.register(Country)
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (_('Description'),
         {'fields':
              ['slug', 'name', 'area']
          }
         ),
        (_('Stats'),
         {'fields':
              ['mp', 'agm', 'fg', 'ufg']
          }
         ),
    ]

    inlines = [LocationCupInLine, ChampionCupInLine, StatsEditionInline, MatchTeamOneInline, MatchTeamTwoInline]

    list_display = ['slug', 'name', 'area', 'mp', 'agm', 'fg', 'ufg', 'cups_counter', 'location_counter']
    list_filter = ['name', 'area', 'mp', 'agm', 'fg', 'ufg']
    list_editable = ['slug', 'name', 'area', 'mp', 'fg', 'ufg']
    search_fields = ['name', 'area', 'mp', 'agm', 'fg', 'ufg']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}

    def cups_counter(self, obj):
        return obj.cups.all().count()

    cups_counter.short_description = _('Cups')
    cups_counter.allow_tags = True

    def location_counter(self, obj):
        return obj.location.all().count()

    location_counter.short_description = _('Location')
    location_counter.allow_tags = True
```

El problema viene cuando tengo que diferencias cada administrador incrustado por el rol que ejerce ese inline: Viene claro en el nombre, una cosa es contar el País como Campeón de una copa, a contarlo como Sede de la Copa.

Para ello me valgo de `verbose_name` para cada uno de ellos, como se puede ver en los incrustados, el problema es que directamente en plantilla no me imprime el tìtulo personalizado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, no se diferencia un incrustado de otro, hay dos nombres repetidos, pero traen modelos completamente diferentes.

Como puedo personalizar el `verbose_name`de un administrador incrustado? Hay alguna limitante de la ùltima versiòn de Django que impida personalizar los tìtulos correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nombre descriptivo o `verbose_name`aplica para `querys`que únicamente retornan un sólo resultado. 
Cuando el 'query' tiene más de un resultado es necesario aplicar el nombre descriptivo plural, osea el `verbose_name_plural`, que es el que el sistema administrador va a usar en el caso de que los `query`tengan más de 1 resultado.

Así que al agregar un `verbose_name` lo mejor es agregar adicionalmente `verbose_name_plural`.